# How to append an id to a ListViewItem using SimpleCursorAdapter and SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-cursor

I've been searching on this for a while now, but I can't find anything that could help me solve my problem.

I have a list of categories in a listview. I fetch these from a SQLiteDatabase and use a SimpleCursorAdapter to put them in the list.
This works fine...

Now, if I click a category, I want to launch a new activity displaying all items with that specific category. Passing parameters to the new activity isn't a problem - found a nice tutorial on how to do this here: [Passing data or parameter to another activity](http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2009/08/passing-data-or-parameter-to-another-activity-android/)

My problem is that I can't get the id out of the selected view... I want the id from the selected category so I can get the items with that categoryId.
This is where I try and get the id out of the view - I've used a lot of different methods  (including some fiddling with listview, item and position, ... this is my most recent attempt) and don't know what to try next...

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View item, int position,
            long itemId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bun = new Bundle();

        bun.putInt("categoryId", (int) itemId);

        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ItemsPerCategoryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bun);          
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Has anybody encountered the same problem and if you have, do you have some advice for me on how to do this?

This is how the problem got solved:

```
        Cursor c = (Cursor)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(_ID)); //0 = index id
        //Log.d("Category id", id + "");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bun = new Bundle();

        bun.putInt("categoryId", id);

        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ItemsPerCategoryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bun);          
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What does your ArrayAdapter hold? What type of Object?

Comment: @Diëgo when youre building a query for SimpleCursorAdapter put this "categoryID as _id" so itemId will return categoryID

Comment: @Carnal: I do not use an ArrayAdapter... I use a ListAdapter:
        Cursor c = getCategoryCursor(db);
        ListAdapter  categoryAdapter = getCategoryAdapter(c);

Comment: @Selvin: new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, new String[] {TITLE, _ID as _id}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
makes my app FC at onCreate(); I must have misunderstood?

Comment: @Diëgo `new String[] {TITLE, _ID as _id}` is only pointing adapter which columns should be mapped to text1, text2 views ... you have to include em in your cursor show us logcat log and getCategoryCursor code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View item, int position,
        long itemId) {

    Cursor c = (Cursor)adatper.getItem(position); //adapter = cursor adapter object
    int id = c.getInt(0)// 0 is index of id.
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle bun = new Bundle();

    bun.putInt("categoryId", id);

    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ItemsPerCategoryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bun);          
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!
[code]Cursor c = (Cursor)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
   int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(_ID)); //0 = index id
   //Log.d("Category id", id + "");
   
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   Bundle bun = new Bundle();
   
   bun.putInt("categoryId", id);
   
   intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ItemsPerCategoryActivity.class);
   intent.putExtras(bun);   
   startActivity(intent);[/code]

Answer (score 0):

For this,you have can use custom adapter and there,you can set ids in a HashMap.Here is an example:

```
    public class DemoAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
    {
        Cursor dataCursor;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context context;

        public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();    

        public DemoAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,int[] to)
        {
            super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
            this.context=context;
            this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.fromWhere=fromWhere;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);
                     holder = new ViewHolder();

                     holder.cName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);        
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

            String id=Integer.toString(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            myList.put(position, id);

            holder.cName.setText(dataCursor.getString("contact_name"));

            return convertView;
       }

       static class ViewHolder
       {
          TextView cName;          
       }
  }
```

Now,use it like-

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener{

                  @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {

                         int id=Integer.parseInteger(DemoAdapter.myList.get(position));     
            }
});
```